# Avoid twisting artifacts in spline extrusion?

Tags: c++, opengl, curve, spline, glm-math

I am trying to attach 2d shape profiles to a spline curve. At certain points in the spline I get the weird twisting artifacts in my geometry as shown in the image. How can I avoid this using the Frenet-Frame equations?

My current calculations for the normal, binormal and tangent:

```
forward_tangent_vector = glm::normalize(pointforward - pointmid);
backward_tangent_vector = glm::normalize(pointmid - pointback);
second_order_tangent = glm::normalize(forward_tangent_vector - backward_tangent_vector);
binormal = glm::normalize(glm::cross(forward_tangent_vector,second_order_tangent));
normal = glm::normalize(glm::cross(binormal, forward_tangent_vector));

//translation matrix
T = glm::translate(T, pointmid);

normal_axis = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
rotationAxis = glm::cross(normal_axis, forward_tangent_vector);
rotationAngle = glm::acos(glm::dot(normal_axis, forward_tangent_vector));

//rotation matrix
R = glm::rotate(R, glm::degrees(rotationAngle), rotationAxis);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You fell victim to the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem):

> A common problem in computer graphics is to generate a non-zero vector in R3 that is orthogonal to a given non-zero one. There is no single continuous function that can do this for all non-zero vector inputs. This is a corollary of the hairy ball theorem. To see this, consider the given vector as the radius of a sphere and note that finding a non-zero vector orthogonal to the given one is equivalent to finding a non-zero vector that is tangent to the surface of that sphere where it touches the radius. However, the hairy ball theorem says there exists no continuous function that can do this for every point on the sphere (i.e. every given vector).

Also see this: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/10/oriented-fish-and-hairy-balls.html

The problem lies in these two lines:

```
normal_axis = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
rotationAxis = glm::cross(normal_axis, forward_tangent_vector);
```

When `forward_tangent_vector` is colinear with `(0,1,0)`, `rotationAxis` becomes `(0,0,0)`. That's why you get a jolt in your pipe.

What you need to do instead of hardcoding `(0,1,0)`, is to take the first derivative of the spline (velocity/tangent vector), take the second derivative of the spline (acceleration/normal vector), and take their cross products (binormal). Normalize these three vectors and you get the so-called [Frenet-frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas), a set of 3 mutually perpendicular vectors around the spline.

Note that your spline has to be C2-continuous, otherwise you would get similar "twists" caused by the discontinuities in the second derivative (aka. acceleration/normal vector).

Once you have the Frenet-frame, it's a matter of a simple change of basis to work in that coordinate system. Don't mess around with `glm::rotate`, just put the x,y,z unit vectors into a matrix as rows (or columns? I'm not sure what convention GLM uses...) and that'll be your transformation matrix.

Comment: Well the problem is I can't ensure if the curve will be C2 continuous. The curve is generated by an algorithm which may or may not provide C2 continuous curve. Once I have the `tbn` matrix how do I change basis of these circle profiles(2d shapes).

Comment: Just multiply the vertices with this matrix. Also don't forget to translate the origin to the Frenet-frame's origin.

Comment: Using Fernet frames won't help you to fully solve this kind of problem since The Frenet frame on a non-convex curve reverses the direction of the normal fields. You will need to use rotation-minimizing frames to avoid the problem. This paper explains it https://faculty.engineering.ucdavis.edu/farouki/wp-content/uploads/sites/41/2013/02/Rational-rotation-minimizing-frames.pdf